# In ST:TOS when is the first time we see the Starship Enterprise use her phasers?

Tags: star-trek, phaser

I've looked at [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phaser_bank), [Weapons in Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapons_in_Star_Trek) amongst others but there does seem to be an answer. Looking at the [List of TOS episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series_episodes) I'm suspecting [Balance of Terror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_of_Terror).
Does anyone know when the Enterprise first used her phasers that we can actually see?

Comment: No. I wanted chronological order. The first time we see her firing. Not logical time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In episode 10 of the first season, "The Corbomite Maneuver", *Enterprise* destroys a warning buoy after it begins emitting dangerous levels of radiation.

[image: warning buoy]

[image: enterprise firing]